# query has no destination for result data (RETURNS TRIGGER)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have got an issue where on insert I want to update instead if the customerID exists in a separate table called leadCustomer. I'm receiving the error in the title and honestly have no idea why, if anyone could give any advice I would really appreciate it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Ins_FlightBooking
BEFORE INSERT ON FlightBooking
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_Lead();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_Lead()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$BODY$
    BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM FlightBooking, LeadCustomer;
      IF FlightBooking.CustomerID = LeadCustomer.CustomerID
      THEN UPDATE FlightBooking AS fb
      SET NumSeats = OLD + NEW, TotalCost = OLD + NEW
      FROM fb JOIN LeadCustomer AS lc ON
      fb.CustomerID = lc.CustomerID
      WHERE fb.CustomerID != lc.CustomerID;
      END IF;
    END;
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Many thanks, 
Callum

Comment: Why are you retrieving **all** rows from `FlightBooking` **and** `LeadCustomer`??

Comment: Just so it works for now

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be several quite fundamental errors here:

- As the error says, there is nowhere for the results of your `SELECT` statement to go.
- On the next line, you access `FlightBooking` and `LeadCustomer` as though they are records or rows; presumably you expect these to come from the `SELECT`, but which row would they contain?
- Later, you write `OLD + NEW`, but `OLD` and `NEW` are records - they represent the whole row the trigger is being run for, not any particular column.
- This is an `INSERT` trigger, so there are no `OLD` values, only the `NEW` ones being inserted.
- You `JOIN LeadCustomer` on the `CustomerID` column, but that row won't have been inserted yet, because this is a `BEFORE` trigger.
- You also have a `WHERE` clause that contradicts your `ON` clause, so no rows can possibly match (`ON fb.CustomerID = lc.CustomerID WHERE fb.CustomerID != lc.CustomerID`)
- You don't `RETURN` anything to indicate whether the original `INSERT` should go ahead or not.

If you look at [the Postgres manual for triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html), you'll see a few examples, and I don't want to write your code for you because I think it's better to learn by trying, but here are some hints:

- Your main condition is if there is a row matching the inserted `CustomerID` (which will be in the variable `NEW.CustomerID`) in the table `LeadCustomer`; you could use an `IF EXISTS (...)` query to see if there is a row matching this condition.
- In your update, you want to add the values from `NEW` (the inserted row) to an existing row in the table, not to `OLD`.
- I don't think you need the `JOIN` in that update, just to match `WHERE CustomerID = NEW.CustomerID`, but I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to do.
- If you run the update, you want to skip the insert so `RETURN NULL`; if you *don't* run the update, you need to tell Postgres to go ahead with the insert, so `RETURN NEW` (this is explained in the manual).

Comment: And you have to `CREATE FUNCTION` before you can `CREATE TRIGGER` that uses the function.